# Pascals to PSI formula

Tags: physics

Could somebody give me a formula to convert Pascals to PSI? I understand that you probably have to convert Pounds of Force to Newtons. But where do I go from there?

Comment: This ought to be in [physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/). Anyway, typing `pascal to PSI` in Google nets you the conversion factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, a pound-force is 4.4482216152605 N exactly. An inch is by definition 0.0254 meters exactly, so
$$1\,\text{PSI} = \frac{4.4482216152605\,\mathrm N}{(0.0254\,\mathrm m)^2} \approx 6894.75729\,\mathrm{Pa}$$
or
$$1 = 6894.75729 \frac{\mathrm{Pa}}{\mathrm{PSI}}$$
Divide your pascal magnitude by this unity, and you will get the same magnitude expressed in PSI.